# How do I convert VARCHAR Column into NUMBER?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to convert my whole Column (Donation) into a number while it's a varchar in Oracle db. When I use the TO_NUMBER function I get missing right parenthesis and invalid number errors.

I have tried The to_number function to no avail.

```
    insert into DD (Donor_ID, Donation_ID, Donation_Type, Donation, Inventory_ID) values 
   (1, 1, 'Food', 'Oranges', 1);
   insert into DD (Donor_ID, Donation_ID, Donation_Type, Donation, Inventory_ID) values 
   (2, 2, 'Currency', 200, 2);
   insert into DD (Donor_ID, Donation_ID, Donation_Type, Donation, Inventory_ID) values 
   (3, 3, 'Currency', 300, 2);
   insert into DD (Donor_ID, Donation_ID, Donation_Type, Donation, Inventory_ID) values 
   (4, 4, 'Currency', 400, 2);
   insert into DD (Donor_ID, Donation_ID, Donation_Type, Donation, Inventory_ID) values 
   (5, 5, 'Currency', 500, 2);

select di.Donor_Name DI, 
    acz.Address_City ACZ, 
    dd.Donation_Type DD, 
    TO_NUMBER('500' from dd.Donation DD) 

from DI di, ACZ acz, DD dd  
where dd.Donation_Type = 'Currency' AND dd.Donation > 499 
order by Donor_Name
```

The result I want is to display the donations > 499. Which should only be one row displayed.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database supports `to_number()` the syntax is:

```
select di.Donor_Name DI, 
       acz.Address_City ACZ, 
       dd.Donation_Type as DD, 
       to_number(dd.Donation) 
from DI di join
     ACZ acz
     on ? join  -- MISSING JOIN CONDITION
     DD dd 
     on ?       -- MISSING JOIN CONDITION
where dd.Donation_Type = 'Currency' AND dd.Donation > 499 
order by Donor_Name;
```

You left out all your `join` conditions.

In most databases, you would solve the problem by storing the value using the correct datatype.  You can also `cast()` the value:

```
cast(dd.donation as numeric(15, 4))  -- or whatever
```